# To show sequence $a_n = n$ is not convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here is proof that sequence n is not convergent. It is from the book *A Basic Course in Real Analysis* by Ajit Kumar, S. Kumaresan, [page 31](https://books.google.com/books?id=UnfOBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA31).

I have not understood last three lines of the proof. Can anyone explain to me proof.

> **Example 2.1.12.** Consider the sequence $x_n=n$. It is not difficult to see intuitively that this sequence does not converge. Assume the contrary.
>   Let $x_n$ converge to a real number $x$. For $\varepsilon=1$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that the tail of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge N}$ lies in the interval $(x-1,x+1)$ . In particular, $n\in(x-1,x+1)$ for all $n\ge N$. If we let $M:= \max\{x+1,N-1\}$, then $M$ is an upper bound for $\mathbb N$. This contradicts the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property). hence we conclude that $(x_n)$  is not convergent.

Thanks

Comment: Cannot see the image anymore.

Comment: @KittyL there is some problem .when i upload it it shows rotated image

Comment: It was OK the first time you uploaded it.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What book is it from?

Comment: @MartinSleziak http://www.amazon.in/A-Basic-Course-Real-Analysis/dp/148221637X

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Please take 2 minutes to learn how to type your question in a readable manner. Thanks.

Comment: @K.Dutta I have typed the proof from your picture. If needed, edit the text further. If you are satisfied with the result, you can remove the pictures.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the proof is by contradiction. So the assumption is that the sequence $x_n=n$, which is the sequence of natural numbers, does converge.

Now by definition, if a sequence converges to some $x$, then for any number $\epsilon>0$, $x_n$ will fall into the interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ eventually. We let this $\epsilon$ be $1$, since it could be arbitrary. So after some $N$, $x_n$ falls into this interval. That means $x-1\leq x_n \leq x+1$ after some $N$.

What the last three lines says is, you split the sequence into two parts: $n\leq N-1$ and $n\geq N$. When $n\geq N$, by assumption, $n\leq x+1$.

That means, $n$ is either less than or equal to $N-1$ (the first part), or less than or equal to $x+1$ (the second part).

Now set $M$ to be the maximum of the two upper bounds, then every $n$ would be less than or equal to $M$, which is a contradiction to the Archimedian principle. Since it says that natural numbers do not have an upper bound.

Comment: Why is n less than or equal to $x-1$ in second part

Comment: That is by the first half of the proof. You said you didn't understand the last three lines, so I assumed you understood the lines before it. Sorry it should be $x+1$. @K.Dutta

Comment: first part of proof says that tail of sequence lies between x-1 and x+1 for n greater than N

Comment: @K.Dutta: Correct. That means all $n$'s after that are in that interval, so less than or equal to $x+1$.

Comment: How is acrchimedian property contradicted ?

Comment: @K.Dutta: Archimedean principle basically says there is always a natural number that can be greater than any real number. Or natural number is unbounded. In this proof, the natural numbers are bounded by $M$. Hence a contradiction.

Comment: Hell i am not getting this

Comment: @K.Dutta: I edited the answer a little. See if you can understand.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I can't see any picture. But:

**First way**

For all $n\in\mathbb N,$ 
$$|a_{n+1}-a_n|=1,$$

and thus is not a Cauchy sequence. Therefore, it doesn't converge.

**Second way**

Let $x_n=n$. Therefore 
$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$
where $a_k=1$ for all $k$.

We can remark that $$\lim_{k\to\infty }a_k=1,$$
and thus $(x_n)$ doesn't converge.

**Third way**

Using the definition, suppose that there is an $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty }n=x.$$

Then,
$$|n-x|<1$$
if $n>N$ for a certain $N\in\mathbb N$. But this imply that if $n>N$, we have that 
$$0<n<1+x$$
and thus that $\mathbb N$ is bounded. Contradiction.

Comment: I donot know about this concept yet

Answer (score 0):

You may instead show the divergence by showing that for every $M > 0$ there is an $N \geq 1$ such that $n \geq M$ for all $n \geq N.$ 
But, given an $M > 0,$ if $N := \lceil M \rceil$ then $n \geq M$ for all $n \geq N,$ 
so we are done.

Note that $\lceil M \rceil$ denotes the least integer upper bound for $M$.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent to a point $l$ if $\forall~\epsilon>0, \exists~m\in \mathbb N$ such that $|a_n-l|<\epsilon$ whenever $n \ge m$.

So, **In general**, for a particular $\epsilon>0 $, there exists a corresponding value of $m$.

If the sequence $\{n\}$ was indeed convergent, for $\epsilon=1$, there should exist an $m$ such that $|n-l|<1$ whenever $n \ge m$, which means

$\forall~n \ge m : l-1 < n < l+1~~~~.....(1)$.

This is clearly absurd because, select : $n = \max(m, l+1)$ or any integer greater than $l+1$ for that matter, this is possible because $n$ is free to choose any integral value and can extend upto infinity. That $n$ won't fit into the inequality $(1)$.

And hence, the given sequence cannot be convergent.

Answer (score 0):

It's better thinking to general results, before doing a particular case.

The fact that a sequence converges, means its term approach the limit when the index becomes large. In more formal ways, $l$ is the limit of the sequence $(x_n)$ if

> for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $m$ such that, for $n>m$, $|x_n-l|<\varepsilon$

Now we apply this with $\varepsilon=1$, but any positive number will do. If the sequence converges to $l$, we know that, for $n>m$,
$$
l-1<x_n<l+1
$$
So we can conclude that
$$
\min\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_m,l-1\}
\le x_n\le
\max\{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_m,l+1\}
$$
for *all* $n$.

Therefore a convergent sequence is *bounded*: there are $A$ and $B$ such that
$$
A\le x_n\le B
$$
for all $n$.

Since the sequence $x_n=n$ is not bounded, we are done.

Note that this is only a necessary condition for convergence: it's easy to show a bounded sequence that's not convergent, for instance $x_n=(-1)^n$. However, such a criterion can easily exclude convergence without doing many computations.